# Wix Velo Repeater.onItemReady showing correct variables in console.log but placing last item into text fields on-site

Tags: velo

The final page I am trying to create and make work: [text](https://www.chamonix360.com/test)
This simplified page recreates my problem: [text](https://www.chamonix360.com/test3)

I got a collection called "Trails" which include the trail specifications (lenght, elevation, etc) and I got a collection "TrailArticles" which has the content for specific articles where I list specific trails for a certain theme. To pull the data out of the Trails collection I do this:

```
$w.onReady(function () {
    $w("#repeater1").onItemReady(($item, itemData, index) => {

        console.log("title:"  + itemData.trail.title);
        let testElevUp = String(itemData.trail.elevUp);
        console.log("testElevUp:"  + testElevUp);
        $w('#text251').text = testElevUp        
    });
});
```

The console shows the correct values:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPirW.png)

For some reason the textbox on the site shows the last value in the collection for all items in the repeater. I have used this method all over the site to reference data from 2 linked collections. For instance here: [text](https://www.chamonix360.com/pointsofinterest/cascade-du-berard)

Same method used, same code. Same kind of data model with a one-to-one reference collection linking the data. To me this feels like a Wix bug or is there another explanation?

I have not tried anything else. This method is the way to do it and I have applied Repeater.onItemReady in many location on the site to pull data out of a collection, apply for a formatting rule to it through Velo code and then present it on the site. I have no clue why this simply code snippet is not working in this particular case.